# Checking if current day is the changing day between CET and CEST

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, timezone, php-carbon

I know how to check the transitions in the year, with

```
$to = (clone $from)->addYear;
$arrTrans = $tz->getTransitions($from->timestamp, $to->timestamp);
```

The first element of the array is always the current day. Here it will return 3 elements, the current day, and the 2 days that change

So, if I want to know if the current day is a transition, and I do:

```
$to = (clone $from)->addDay();
$arrTrans = $tz->getTransitions($from->timestamp, $to->timestamp);
```

I will always get the current day, but it will not tell me if it is the transition day.

Is it really mandatory to compare with last day, and check that `isdst` attribute is different or is there a nice way to do it ?

Comment: Are you sure that CST (Central Standard Time in North America) and not CET (Central European Time) is meant?

Comment: oh, yes, it is CET indeed, I will correct it right now

Answer (score 0):

I ended up searching for the last sunday of march and the last sunday of october.

If this is the current day, I would respectively delete the last hour, or adding an extra hour, copying the latest value I have.

Did not find better way to do it.

Comment: Reading your answer, I suspect that your problem is different from the heading of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking whether there is a change between winter / summer time on a certain date is not difficult. If that day is summer or winter time, the following day is different.

```
function isDayChangeCETtoCEST(DateTimeInterface $dt){
  $dayC = (clone $dt)->setTime(0,0,0);
  $flag0 = $dayC->format('I');
  $flag1 = $dayC->setTime(24,0,0)->format('I');
  return $flag0 == 0 AND $flag1 == 1;
}

function isDayChangeCESTtoCET(DateTimeInterface $dt){
  $dayC = (clone $dt)->setTime(0,0,0);
  $flag0 = $dayC->format('I');
  $flag1 = $dayC->setTime(24,0,0)->format('I');
  return $flag0 == 1 AND $flag1 == 0;
}
```

How are the functions used?

```
$date = new DateTime('2021-10-31');
$isChange = isDayChangeCESTtoCET($date);  //bool(true)
```